# WCF static singleton loses its values

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I have a wcf with a application global static variable.  This variable loses all its values and resets?  What could cause this to happen?  How can I avoid it?

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate a little on when/how it resets. Code would help as well...

Comment: Do you mean the variable reset for different requests or in the same request?

Comment: Shutdown worker processes after being idle for x minutes could this cause it?  It seems to work for a while then randomly stops working.  Basically the values saved in memory are gone.  The static is global for all.

Comment: In that case it looks like what hemp is describing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this WCF service is hosted in IIS, it is likely you are falling victim to automatic app pool recycling.

See the Recycling section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx#msdnwcfhc_topic5